# Method handle invocation result as an argument

Tags: java, methods

I have the following 2 method handles:

```
MethodHandle intConcatenator = MethodHandles.publicLookup()
   .findStatic(Concat.class, "concat", MethodType.methodType(int.class, int.class, int.class));

MethodHandle randomIntProvider = MethodHandles.publicLookup()
   .findStatic(IntProvider.class, "provideRandom", MethodType.methodType(int.class));
```

Is it possible to create a `MethodHandle` that accepts no arguments and will perform invokation of `randomIntProvider` twice and provides their result as an argument to `intConcatenator`? I can do this as follows:

```
MethodHandle newConcatenator = MethodHandles.insertArguments(
           intConcatenator, 
           0, 
           randomIntProvider.invoke(), 
           randomIntProvider.invoke()
);
```

But the problem is that the argumets to `intConcatenator` are evaluated once at the inserting time (but I want `randomIntProvider` is evaluated each time, not just once at the inserting time).

Is it possible to create such a `MethodHandle`?

Comment: Question: why do this with reflection?  You have the exact class types, why not just define a method on that type and then call it?

Comment: @markspace I'm solving a bit more complex task actually, so `MethodHandles` are useful. Btw, what's wrong with `MethodHandle`s?

Comment: Mostly "what's wrong" is that this would be far simpler if one just used class types.  Simpler code is easier to maintain, and doesn't have these weird side effects.  If your problem can be solved with simple class types, you probably should do it that way.

Comment: @markspace Yes, I completely agree with you about simplicity. But in my particular case `MethodHandle`s could simplify the code without much performance penalty.

Comment: It sounds like it might be better to describe your original problem. This would help determine if this way is truly the simplest way, and if it might actually solve your issue.